# fetch unable to send header in proper format

Tags: javascript

I am sending headers file in `isomorphic-fetch` like this:

```
fetch(url, {
                method: "GET",
                headers: {
                    'Access-Key': headers['X-Access-Key'],
                    'Access-Token': headers['X-Access-Token']
                },
            }).then(function(response){
```

It is giving me error.. The headers are not as expected I guess..

I tried this on online api test and it works there ..

There I get the response like :

```
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
User-Agent: runscope/0.1
Access-Key: D0NsOdfdfwfdsdeY6xPcw2goQ8S2H9UiY2QYZOP7t
Access-Token: yKIY3AoVUzADcHfdfdfdfdfdbep5raKVzZl1lg67E3ZZjUNRkE0Bu8l0FZ
```

I do not know what is wrong when I send the headers.. I think it should work but not. How can I send headers on this format ?

Help is appriciated

Comment: It's not very clear from your question what you expect the outcome of your process to be. Can you include more context about what you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: Not much to go on here but make sure you use a ES6 promise compatible polyfill like [es6-promise](https://github.com/jakearchibald/es6-promise) when using isomorphic-fetch

Comment: this question has nothing to do with react or redux. its your fetch library.